# Solid red light on Samsung CLP-325W

Tags: printer, laser-printer

I'm getting a solid red light on my Samsung CLP-325W printer. The printer started showing this error when I was low on 2 color toners. I've bought the official toners from Samsung. however I'm no longer getting the errors about low toner, but I'm getting a solid red light.

I've also tried to observe this printer via the "Smart Panel." Any attempts to print fail.

Other notes: 
This printer is connected to my network via an ethernet cable. I can view the printer's page. However that does not report any particular errors.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Samsung](http://support-us.samsung.com/cyber/popup/iframe/pop_troubleshooting_fr.jsp?modelname=CLP-325W&idx=377467&modelcode=&), any of these conditions can cause the On Line LED to glow solid red:

- Printer paper is jammed inside your printer.
- A cover is not closed properly.
- The toner cartridge is not inserted properly and needs to be reinstalled.
- The toner cartridge is running low.
- There is no paper in the paper tray.
- The paper inside the paper tray is not installed correctly.

If you've looked and it's none of these, then check for blocked/broken sensors and switches that may cause the printer to think one of these conditions is true.

Comment: I replaced the Yellow one and it went to work. It never claimed that that one was low.

Comment: Well it just went back to red.